# PowerShell Active Directory - Can't use array value in filter for Get-ADUser

Tags: arrays, powershell, filter, active-directory, get-aduser

I have two variables; `$test` and `$accounts[0].upn`

Both are Strings, both contain the exact same value.

When I run:

`Get-ADUser -Filter "UserPrincipalName -eq '$test'"`

I get the result I want, however when I run:

`Get-ADUser -Filter "UserPrincipalName -eq '$accounts[0].upn'"`

It does not return any result.

I get that $accounts is an array, but I thought I should get the same result given the variables are both of same type and value.

See my screenshot below a better understanding of what I am trying to achieve, I only made the `$test` variable for debugging and I would like the command to work with `$accounts[0].upn`. Apologies I had to black out some personal information for privacy reasons, it shouldn't hinder understanding the screenshot.

[Demonstration Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDzWZ.png)

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that powershell doesnt know when to stop interpreting the variable within the string (its called [expression expansion](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/variable-expansion-in-strings-and-here-strings/)).

so to fix this you should wrap any variable with properties in a sub expression so powershell knows when to stop expanding it.

`Get-ADUser -Filter "UserPrincipalName -eq '$accounts[0].upn'"`

Should become

`Get-ADUser -Filter "UserPrincipalName -eq '$($accounts[0].upn)'"`

Note the `$()` with your variable inside it.

Comment: Worked perfectly - Thanks heaps for the answer and explanation!